# Excel: graphing a 3 colums table (column label, column date, column position)

Tags: excel

I have a set of 3 columns:

- keyword (consider it as a kind of tag; there are only 5 distinct)
- dates (today, yesterday, ... 30 days ago)
- a value for each combination of keyword and date

I can easily plot one Line Graph (see the picture below), but I need to plot **all** the lines. I'd like Excel to understand that each different Keyword is a different series.

[image]

[image]

Comment: 1) you need to re-arrange your data so the first column are the date (in chronological order), the first row are the keywords and the content of the table the corresponding values. 2) This question would be better suited to https://superuser.com as it does not concern itself with programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a pivot table or just a table?

If it's a table create a pivot table with the keywords in the Legend series on the top, the dates in the Axis (category) box on the bottom left side and the values in the Values area.

Create a line chart and there you go.

You need to use the pivot table to gather the data in series. You have to present the data in a way that will work for your chart. A flat table is not going to give you what you want.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I would have never guessed by myself